# Given a P-sided dice rolled X times, how can I select P to ensure mimimal odds of rolling M 1's.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we roll a *P*-sided dice 40 times and count how many times we roll a 1.

I know I can calculate the odds of rolling three or more 1's as follows:

$$1 - \frac{(P-1)^{40} + {40 \choose 1 }(P-1)^{39} + {40 \choose 2}(P-1)^{38}}{P^{40}}$$

How can I choose the largest *P* such that I have at least 99% odds?

I know I can do this with direct calculation. For example, with the following table, it is easy to see that the largest P to provide 99%+ odds is 5.

```
| P | Odds of rolling 3 or more 1's |
|---|-------------------------------|
| 2 | 0.9999999993                  |
| 3 | 0.9999804655                  |
| 4 | 0.9989842849                  |
| 5 | 0.9920578627                  |
| 6 | 0.972648811                   |
| 7 | 0.938412889                   |
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to determine the largest such *P* without using direct calculation?
2. Is it possible to generalize this result. In other words, given a *P*-sided dice rolled *X* times, how can we choose *P* such that the odds of rolling at least *M* 1's is at least *Y*?   If I know *X*, *M*, and *Y*, how do I choose the optimal (largest) *P*?  Is direct calculation the only way?
3. If direct calculation is the only way, are there any closed forms (or shorter forms) that would help me express the calculations, particularly as *M* grows?

Comment: After a suggestion from a coworker about poisson, I think a good answer to my question would include a discussion of binomial distribution and poisson distribution.  For my purposes, X will be fairly large (1000+), and I can choose P to be large enough that poisson will be a good approximation, which will probably simplify the optimization I'm trying to perform.